# Using BEM methodology and a small file size

Tags: css, webpack, sass, bem

I'm trying to dive into the BEM methodology. Even though it seems to be the 'must have' methodology for all project sizes, I'm kind of unhappy with it or am I just trying to use it the wrong way?

Using BEM the CSS gets divided into something like this.

```
.block {
  /* Block code goes here */
}

.block--is-hidden {
  /* Block modifier code goes here */
}

.block__element {
  /* Element code goes here */
}
```

This seems to be pretty fine for me, as long as you do not reuse some code. Let's assume I'm using Bootstrap or any other CSS Framework/Library. Doing so I just want to use the grid. That being said my markup could look somehow like that.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to BEM this would be a no go. Instead all the grid classes should be wrapper up in our corresponding block and element classes. A possible way to achieve this would be through SASS and it's `@include`. For me this basically results in **redundant code**.

So my question right now is. Am I missing something? I mean, using BEM while for e.g. loading Bootstraps `.container` code into every single of my own block styling would just result in an **massive** output CSS file. Is my approach correct? And if so - would I really sacrifice initial loading time just for the idea of better organized CSS and better readable markup?

Comment: Define "massive CSS output". You're saying "in the future this could be massive" without any actual numbers to back up your claim. Plus, parsing CSS is quite fast and gzip helps loads with a setup like BEM where patterns in class names are repeated making the transfer of the content a near non-issue. Essentially, you're asking for input on pure conjecture which no one can accurately answer.

Comment: You forgot about gzip/deflate.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason your `block`s have to begin at the container level? I'm not sure if it's a violation of BEM methodology exactly, but I personally "begin" my `block`s more at the html>body>.container level. So:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cheesecake">
      <h1 class="cheesecake__heading"></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html
```

With SCSS looking something like:

```
.cheesecake {
  &__heading {}
}
```

And so on.